# Transpose and Compare

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-structures

I'm attempting to compare two data frames. `Item` and `Summary` variables correspond to various dates and quantities.  I'd like to transpose the dates into one column of data along with the associated quantities.  I'd then like to compare the two data frames and see what changed from `PreviousData` to `CurrentData`.

Previous Data:

```
PreviousData = { 'Item' : ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx','yza','uaza','fupa'],
                'Summary' : ['party','weekend','food','school','tv','photo','camera','python','r','rstudio','spyder'],
                '2022-01-01' : [1, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,2],
                '2022-02-01' : [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-03-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan],
                '2022-06-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-07-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-08-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-09-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                '2022-10-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-11-01' : [np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-12-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-01-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-02-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-03-01' : [np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                '2023-06-01' : [1,1,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-07-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-08-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-09-01' : [np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
               }
PreviousData = pd.DataFrame(PreviousData)

PreviousData
```

Current Data:

```
CurrentData = { 'Item' : ['ghi','stu','abc','mno','jkl','pqr','def','vwx','yza'],
               'Summary' : ['food','camera','party','tv','school','photo','weekend','python','r'],
                '2022-01-01' : [3, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                '2022-02-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-03-01' : [np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-06-01' : [2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-07-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-08-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-09-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,3,3,np.nan,np.nan,5,5],
                '2022-10-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-11-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-12-01' : [np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-01-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-02-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-03-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,2,np.nan,2],
                '2023-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,2],
               }
CurrentData = pd.DataFrame(CurrentData)
CurrentData
```

As requested, here's an example of a difference:

[image]

How to transpose and compare these two sets?

Comment: Why transpose? Compare how? Can you make your example more minimal (5 rows/cols is probably enough), explain the logic, and provide the expected output?

Comment: Because you generally don't want to have data be a part of the column headers (i.e., metadata) @mozway

Comment: Example:

In ```PreviousData```, Item ```abc``` had a value of ```1``` for ```2022-01-01```.  In the ```CurrentData```, it has that same value for ```2022-02-01``` instead. @mozway

Comment: Can you provide the full explicit output?

Comment: @mozway I've added a picture of an example where the date is different in the ```PreviousData``` and ```CurrentData``` for ```Item``` ```abc```.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question ;)

Comment: @mozway the below is what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is the following. Transpose both dataframes:

```
PreviousData_t = PreviousData.melt(id_vars=["Item", "Summary"], 
    var_name="Date", 
    value_name="value1")
```

which is

```
   Item  Summary        Date  value1
0     abc    party  2022-01-01     1.0
1     def  weekend  2022-01-01     NaN
2     ghi     food  2022-01-01     NaN
3     jkl   school  2022-01-01     1.0
4     mno       tv  2022-01-01     NaN
..    ...      ...         ...     ...
226   stu   camera  2023-09-01     NaN
227   vwx   python  2023-09-01     1.0
228   yza        r  2023-09-01     NaN
229  uaza  rstudio  2023-09-01     NaN
230  fupa   spyder  2023-09-01     NaN
```

and

```
CurrentData_t = CurrentData.melt(id_vars=["Item", "Summary"], 
    var_name="Date", 
    value_name="value2")

  Item  Summary        Date  value2
0    ghi     food  2022-01-01     3.0
1    stu   camera  2022-01-01     NaN
2    abc    party  2022-01-01     NaN
3    mno       tv  2022-01-01     1.0
4    jkl   school  2022-01-01     NaN
..   ...      ...         ...     ...
139  jkl   school  2023-04-01     NaN
140  pqr    photo  2023-04-01     2.0
141  def  weekend  2023-04-01     NaN
142  vwx   python  2023-04-01     NaN
143  yza        r  2023-04-01     2.0

[144 rows x 4 columns]
```

THen merge:

```
Compare = PreviousData_t.merge(CurrentData_t, on =['Date','Item','Summary'], how = 'left')
     Item  Summary        Date  value1  value2
0     abc    party  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN
1     def  weekend  2022-01-01     NaN     NaN
2     ghi     food  2022-01-01     NaN     3.0
3     jkl   school  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN
4     mno       tv  2022-01-01     NaN     1.0
..    ...      ...         ...     ...     ...
226   stu   camera  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN
227   vwx   python  2023-09-01     1.0     NaN
228   yza        r  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN
229  uaza  rstudio  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN
230  fupa   spyder  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN

[231 rows x 5 columns]
```

and compare by creating a column marking differences

```
Compare['diff'] = np.where(Compare['value1']!=Compare['value2'], 1,0)

Item  Summary        Date  value1  value2  diff
0     abc    party  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN     1
1     def  weekend  2022-01-01     NaN     NaN     1
2     ghi     food  2022-01-01     NaN     3.0     1
3     jkl   school  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN     1
4     mno       tv  2022-01-01     NaN     1.0     1
..    ...      ...         ...     ...     ...   ...
226   stu   camera  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN     1
227   vwx   python  2023-09-01     1.0     NaN     1
228   yza        r  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN     1
229  uaza  rstudio  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN     1
230  fupa   spyder  2023-09-01     NaN     NaN     1

[231 rows x 6 columns]
```

If you only want to compare those entries that are common to both, do this:

```
Compare = PreviousData_t.merge(CurrentData_t, on =['Date','Item','Summary'])

Compare['diff'] = np.where(Compare['value1']!=Compare['value2'], 1,0)

 Item  Summary        Date  value1  value2  diff
0    abc    party  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN     1
1    def  weekend  2022-01-01     NaN     NaN     1
2    ghi     food  2022-01-01     NaN     3.0     1
3    jkl   school  2022-01-01     1.0     NaN     1
4    mno       tv  2022-01-01     NaN     1.0     1
..   ...      ...         ...     ...     ...   ...
139  mno       tv  2023-04-01     NaN     NaN     1
140  pqr    photo  2023-04-01     NaN     2.0     1
141  stu   camera  2023-04-01     NaN     NaN     1
142  vwx   python  2023-04-01     1.0     NaN     1
143  yza        r  2023-04-01     NaN     2.0     1

[144 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: An example of the ```diff``` column I'm not understanding is ```Item``` 230.  Why is there a value of 1 when both ```value1``` and ```value2``` didn't change? @SergedeGossondeVarennes

Comment: @HelpMeCode That is because the join (merge) I did was 'left'. That is, I took all the rows of PreviousData and merged so, if fupa and spyder weren't present in CurrentData, they'll be automatically defined as NaN.

Comment: @HelpMeCode I updated with an answer that only compares common data to both df.

Comment: why would line 139 have a ```1``` in the ```diff``` column?  There doesn't seem to be a change from ```value1``` to ```value2```

Comment: Ah, I may have dawned on an update.  Perform the ```Compare.replace({np.nan: ''})```.  This will remove the NaNs in the output and won't show a ```1``` in the diff column. :-)