# How can I partially match numbers to strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Inspired from [Transpose and Compare | Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420985/transpose-and-compare-python), but now I'd like to introduce the complexity of partial matching.

Data:

```
PreviousData = { 'Item' : ['abc-023','def-78','ghi-012','jkl-100','mno-01','pqr-890','stu-024','vwx-765','yza-789','uaza-400','fupa-499'],
                'Summary' : ['party','weekend','food','school','tv','photo','camera','python','r','rstudio','spyder'],
                '2022-01-01' : [1, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,2],
                '2022-02-01' : [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-03-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan],
                '2022-06-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-07-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-08-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-09-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                '2022-10-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-11-01' : [np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-12-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-01-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-02-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-03-01' : [np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                '2023-06-01' : [1,1,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-07-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-08-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-09-01' : [np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
               }
PreviousData = pd.DataFrame(PreviousData)

PreviousData




CurrentData = { 'Item' : ['ghi-012:XYZ','stu-024:Z','abc-023-100','mno-01-100:Z','jkl-100:Z-900','pqr-890-FR','def-78-RF-FR','vwx-765:NCVE','yza-789-YU'],
               'Summary' : ['food','camera','party','tv','school','photo','weekend','python','r'],
                '2022-01-01' : [3, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                '2022-02-01' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-03-01' : [np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-05-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-06-01' : [2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-07-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-08-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-09-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,3,3,np.nan,np.nan,5,5],
                '2022-10-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-11-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2022-12-01' : [np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-01-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-02-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                '2023-03-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,2,np.nan,2],
                '2023-04-01' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,2],
               }
CurrentData = pd.DataFrame(CurrentData)
CurrentData
```

Examples of partial matches are: abc-023 vs abc-023-100; stu-024 vs stu-024:Z, etc.

Code Tried:

```
PreviousData_t = PreviousData.melt(id_vars=["Item", "Summary"], 
    var_name="Date", 
    value_name="value1")


CurrentData_t = CurrentData.melt(id_vars=["Item", "Summary"], 
    var_name="Date", 
    value_name="value2")


Compare = PreviousData_t.merge(CurrentData_t, on =['Date','Item','Summary'], how = 'left')

Compare['diff'] = np.where(Compare['value1']!=Compare['value2'], 1,0)
#Code Does Not Take Into Account for Partial Matches of Items
```

Any tips on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How should the output look like? Just write a one line DF with 3 columns previous, current and diff.

Comment: That would work @Drakax

Comment: No I meant, could you please show us an expected DF output? But only 1 line is enough, just to understand what you want and how to display it.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420985/transpose-and-compare-python @Drakax

Comment: Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. For question titles, it is better to use a short version of the question, rather than a "topic" description; titlecase is not called for; and "tags" are definitely not needed - that's why there are *actual* tags built in to the system. Please also try to *ask a question*; "Any tips are greatly appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What do you want the code to do? Is there any actual existing code representing an attempt at the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of *clustering* problem and I'm going to provide one solution.

After writing this I remembered this was exactly the problem that was addressed by Google refine. You can read about the open-source version *Open refine* here: https://guides.library.illinois.edu/openrefine/clustering

Anyway, for a start I concatenate all strings in the `Item` column and save them in a list `all_items`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prev = list(PreviousData.Item)
curr = list(CurrentData.Item)
all_items = prev+curr
all_items
['abc-023',
 'def-78',
 'ghi-012',
 'jkl-100',
 'mno-01',
 'pqr-890',
 'stu-024',
 'vwx-765',
 'yza-789',
 'uaza-400',
 'fupa-499',
 'ghi-012:XYZ',
 'stu-024:Z',
 'abc-023-100',
 'mno-01-100:Z',
 'jkl-100:Z-900',
 'pqr-890-FR',
 'def-78-RF-FR',
 'vwx-765:NCVE',
 'yza-789-YU']
```

So now you want to group together strings that are similar, for instance `'abc-023'` and `'abc-023-100'` or `'pqr-890'`  and `'dpqr-890-FR'`.  In `all_items` there are at most two similar strings but in general this is a more complex problem as one string can have several similar strings and how to decide which string is the best choice? The solution to this problem is called *clustering*.

About the similarity function: the example seems to suggest that you want to match two strings if one is a substring of the other. In general, there are many similarity functions and you can just pick the one that’s best suited for your application.

I’m going to show a solution that uses `DBSCAN` clustering from `sklearn` and `SequenceMatcher` from `difflib`.
This is probably an overkill in this case but it might be useful for larger datasets and more complex string matching tasks.

```
la = len(all_items)

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

# this is the distance function between string
diff = lambda i,j: 1 - SequenceMatcher(None, all_items[i], all_items[j]).ratio()

# Note: SequenceMatcher ratio goes from 0 to 1, highest similarity is 1
# but since we’re building a distance matrix, highest similarity=minimal distance
diff_matrix = np.zeros((la, la))
for i in range(la):
    for j in range(i, la):
        diff_matrix[i,j] = diff(i,j)
        diff_matrix[j,i] = diff_matrix[i,j]

pd.DataFrame(diff_matrix) # for pretty-printing (note: this is a symmetric matrix)

# all distances over 0.4 are too far (this means two strings match if SequenceMatcher ratio is >0.6)
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.4, min_samples=2, metric='precomputed').fit(diff_matrix)
```

So now we have clustered the strings. How many clusters are there?

```
# number of clusters is the number of unique labels except for noise
labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)
n_clusters_
# 9
```

Since we were starting with 20 items and we get 9 labels it looks like that most of the labels were matched two by two.
These are the clusters of strings:

```
clusters = {'label'+str(k):[] for k in set(labels)}
for k,v in zip(labels, all_items):
    clusters['label'+str(k)].append(v)
clusters
# {‘label0': ['abc-023', 'abc-023-100'],
#  'label1': ['def-78', 'def-78-RF-FR'],
#  'label2': ['ghi-012', 'ghi-012:XYZ'],
#  'label3': ['jkl-100', 'jkl-100:Z-900'],
#  'label4': ['mno-01', 'mno-01-100:Z'],
#  'label5': ['pqr-890', 'pqr-890-FR'],
#  'label6': ['stu-024', 'stu-024:Z'],
#  'label7': ['vwx-765', 'vwx-765:NCVE'],
#  'label8': ['yza-789', 'yza-789-YU'],
#  'label-1': ['uaza-400', 'fupa-499']}
```

9 strings were matched two by two and two strings were unmatched (label =`-1`).

Create a dictionary `normalized_strings` for translating each string to a unique value in each cluster. I am choosing the first value in each group of strings (for instance in group `['abc-023', 'abc-023-100’]` I choose `'abc-023’`.

```
normalized_strings = {all_items[k]: clusters['label'+str(labels[k])][0] if labels[k]>-1 else all_items[k] for k in range(len(all_items))}
normalized_strings
# {‘abc-023': 'abc-023',
#  'def-78': 'def-78',
#  'ghi-012': 'ghi-012',
#  'jkl-100': 'jkl-100',
#  'mno-01': 'mno-01',
#  'pqr-890': 'pqr-890',
#  'stu-024': 'stu-024',
#  'vwx-765': 'vwx-765',
#  'yza-789': 'yza-789',
#  'uaza-400': 'uaza-400',
#  'fupa-499': 'fupa-499',
#  'ghi-012:XYZ': 'ghi-012',
#  'stu-024:Z': 'stu-024',
#  'abc-023-100': 'abc-023',
#  'mno-01-100:Z': 'mno-01',
#  'jkl-100:Z-900': 'jkl-100',
#  'pqr-890-FR': 'pqr-890',
#  'def-78-RF-FR': 'def-78',
#  'vwx-765:NCVE': 'vwx-765',
#  'yza-789-YU': 'yza-789'}
```

With this dictionary you can now "translate" all the string in your dataframes.

About the `diff` function:

```
diff = lambda i,j: 1 - SequenceMatcher(None, all_items[i], all_items[j]).ratio()
diff(0, 13)
# 0.2222222222222222
```

`'abc-023'` and `'abc-023-100'` are very similar, hence little distance

If `SequenceMatcher` is too costly, one could also define a simpler string matching function, for instance two strings match if one is a substring of the other

```
diff = lambda i,j: 1 - int((all_items[i] in all_items[j]) or (all_items[j] in all_items[i]))
diff(0,13) # strings match, no difference
# 0

diff(0,12) # strings do not match
# 1
```

See also:

- [difflib.SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html): a flexible class for comparing pairs of sequences of any type, so long as the sequence elements are hashable
- [sklearn `DBSCAN`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan)
- [DBSCAN demo](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html)

Comment: What is the final output a user can see?  @user2314737

Comment: @HelpMeCode use the dictionary normalized_strings to translate the strings in `CurrentData.Item` and `PreviousData.Item`. This does the matching by substituting a string with its "normalized" form, so that similar string are recognized as the same.